# Prolog: How to perform term expansion on input from shell?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am writing a module `A` which defines [`term_expansion/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2). As a side-effect, when it becomes imported by module `B`, the terms defined in module `B` will be expanded as described in module `A`. However, I did not manage to also expand the terms which come from shell, after a user has loaded `B` using `?- [B].` in an interactive session.
How do I manipulate the queries/directives which come from shell and call them instead?

## Example:

If the user types

```
?- my_append("AB", "CD", L).
```

I want to expand the `my_append`-term to something like this (but not restricted to it) which is then called after expansion:

```
?- extra_args(A0, A1), my_append_with_extra_args(A0, A1, "AB", "CD", L).
```

To be clear: The term-expansion/-manipulation itself is not the problem – what I need to know is the hook which can I use/redefine like `term_expansion/2`.

Comment: just import module A from REPL: `?- [a].`

Comment: @CapelliC A solution, which does not require the user to remember always importing `A` before starting a session, would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate I was looking for is [`expand_query/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=expand_query%2F4).

Comment: Does a simple `goal_expansion/2` rule not suffice? This way, you could use the goal also within your programs, not only from the query.

Comment: @mat `goal_expansion/2` triggers too often. Performing a simple `?- append("a","b",L).` triggers it four times, instead of one time. Also, it is triggered during the `term_expansion/2`-process – and that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @mat Surprisingly, I still haven't found a way to [expand Prolog queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614561/implementing-partial-evaluation-in-swi-prolog) using `goal_expansion/2`. Is this possible somehow?