# Implementing partial evaluation in SWI-Prolog

Tags: macros, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm writing a partial-evaluator for Prolog queries. I tried to expand a query using [`expand_goal/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=expand_goal/2), but it simply unifies the `Input` with the `Output` in this case:

```
:- initialization(main).
main :-
    Input=is_between(1,A,3),expand_goal(Input,Output),writeln(Output).
is_between(A,B,C) :- 
    B>A,B<C.
```

I also tried using [`term_expansion/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_expansion/2), but this causes the program to fail:

```
:- initialization(main).
main :-
    Input=is_between(1,A,3),term_expansion(Input,Output),writeln(Output).
is_between(A,B,C) :- 
    B>A,B<C.
```

Does SWI-Prolog have a built-in predicate that can perform macro-expansion of queries at runtime, as I tried to do here?

Comment: `goal_expansion/2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to expand a Prolog clause using the built-in [`clause/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=clause/2) predicate. This predicate expands the clause like a [hygienic macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro):

```
:- initialization(main).
main :- clause(is_between(1,2,3),B),writeln(B).
is_between(A,B,C) :- A<B,C>B.
```

This example prints `1<2,3>2`.

It is possible to exand multiple clauses using the [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) predicate:

```
:- initialization(main).
main :- find_all_clauses(is_between(1,2,3),B),writeln(B).

find_all_clauses(Predicate,Output) :-
    findall(Predicate1,clause(Predicate,Predicate1),Output1),
    list_to_disjunction(Output1,Output).

list_to_disjunction([A],A).
list_to_disjunction([A|B],(A;B1)) :- list_to_disjunction(B,B1).

is_between(A,B,C) :- A<B,C>B.
is_between(A,B,C) :- B>A,B<C.
```

This example prints `1<2,3>2;2>1,2<3`.

I also wrote [another partial evaluator](https://gist.github.com/jarble/77d1f818b390a4b5668b55a190172639) that expands the goals recursively. There are a few other open-source libraries for partial evaluation in Prolog, such as [*ecce*](https://github.com/leuschel/ecce) and [*logen*](https://github.com/leuschel/logen).